# node-persist - NodeJS

Tags: node.js, node-persist

who explains me on detail how to work the following istructions:

```
var storage = require("node-persist");

var account = {username: "Morris", password: "test"};

storage.initSync();

storage.setItemSync("accounts", accounts);

var myData = storage,getItemSync("accounts");
console.log(myData);
```

I know that `setitemSync()` it used for create a new variable on memory and created a JSON document into "persist" folder.

`getItemSync("nameVariable")` it used for get a variable that i create before with `setitemSync()`. It's correct?

Because the documentation into GitHub is not clear.

Thank all
Morris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. `node-persist` is modelled after the `localStorage` spec which you can find implemented in browsers (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)).

Just a quick note, I would suggest to use the asynchronous counterpart:

```
storage.setItem('foo', 'bar')
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Stored successfully');

        return storage.getItem('foo');
    })
    .then(value =>
        console.log(`Stored value is ${value}.`)
    )
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Just in general: `sync` functions are blocking the [event loop](https://nodesource.com/blog/understanding-the-nodejs-event-loop/) in Node.js. Means, no other function can be executed until the called synchronous function returns.

Hope I could clarify that a little bit :)

Comment: Excellent! Your response is very clear. Thanks so much :)

Comment: Hello. The example in MDN is not clear but the answer above is. I was able to fix my setItem function (which was working before as setItemSync but due to the update was crashed.)    @notion can you add a similar example for the getItem.?   I tried the same promise - then - catch structure but not working

Comment: ``` var encryptedAccount = storage.getItem('accounts')
  //start testing•
  encryptedAccount
  .then(value => {
    return value
  })
  .catch(e => {
    console.error(e);
  })
  //end testing  ```