# Node-Persist getItem() / setItem() into sync function failing

Tags: node.js, node-persist

I have an application which was working but after doing the packages upgrade stop working. node-persist  issue. *The upgrade was required, so please dont suggest the downgrade. :)*

Original Working Version of getting Items:

```
function getAccounts (masterPassword) {
  // use getItemSync to fetch accounts
  var encryptedAccount = storage.getItemSync('accounts')
  var accounts = []

  // decrypt
  if (typeof encryptedAccount !== 'undefined') {
    var bytes = crypto.AES.decrypt(encryptedAccount, masterPassword)
    accounts = JSON.parse(bytes.toString(crypto.enc.Utf8))
  }

  // return accounts array
  return accounts
}



function saveAccounts (accounts, masterPassword) {
  // encrypt accounts
  var encryptedAccounts = crypto.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(accounts), masterPassword)

  // setItemSync
  storage.setItemSync('accounts', encryptedAccounts.toString())
  return accounts
}
```

I followed the question: [node-persist - NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993906/node-persist-nodejs)
and the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage as well as the documentation in the GitHub: https://github.com/simonlast/node-persist but still not working.

Error. Main call:

```
var createdAccount = createAccount({
      username: argv.username,
      password: argv.password
    }, argv.masterPassword)
    console.log('Account created!')
    console.log(createdAccount)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Unable to create account.')
    console.error(e)
  }
```

With the function createAccount:

```
function createAccount (account, masterPassword) {
  var accounts = getAccounts(masterPassword)

  accounts.push(account)

  saveAccounts(accounts, masterPassword)

  return account
}
```

Fails with:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

In this line:

```
accounts = JSON.parse(bytes.toString(crypto.enc.Utf8))
```

Are you able to provide the new version with `storage.getItem()` and `storage.setItem()`

Comment: Any update on this ? Are you able to solve this ?

Comment: The code above was left to the original version: `$ npm -v node-persist`  `6.3.0` . Import: `var storage = require('node-persist')`, Initialization: `storage.initSync()`